# Why does setting background with custom-set-faces no longer work in emacs 24.5.1?

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization

I set a custom color appearance in my `.emacs` using

```
;; color theme
;;
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(setq color-theme-is-global t)
;; base theme
(color-theme-emacs-21)
;;
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:overline nil :inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#F5DEB8" :foreground "#000000" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 110 :width normal :foundry "*" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#008000"))))
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#00D0D0" :underline nil :weight normal))))
 '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#0000FF" :weight normal))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#FF00FF" :slant normal))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground "#00D0D0"))))
 '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "#000000"))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "#0000FF"))))
 '(font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "#0000FF"))))
 )
```

If I run this in emacs 24.5.1, the desired color appearance - the background, in particular - briefly flashes, but is being reset to a white background a split second after. The code coloring apparently still works, though.

There are no errors in the `*Messages*` buffer.

It used to work flawlessly before an emacs update.

Why does this apparently no longer work in emacs 24.5.1, and how do I persistently set colors now, specifically a background color?

Comment: If you remove the color theme stuff -- lines 3, 4 5 and 7 (with `;; color theme` being line number 1), does your background have `#F5DEB8` as its color?  Then, please tell us the background color being set by `color-theme-emacs-21`.  Perhaps you are telling Emacs to set the background color to whatever `color-theme-emacs-21` uses, and then a fraction of a second later, you are telling Emacs to forget about that setting and instead use `#F5DEB8`.

Comment: Also, why does your default face have **:foundry "*"** -- i.e., just an asterisk as the string?  Do you have a link to some documentation that shows this is correct?

Comment: @lawlist Removing lines 3, 4, 5, 7 sets the correct background color, and code coloring seems to be working as well. Thanks!